# Fedora Silverblue : VS code's remote container extension : empty folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, fedora-silverblue, remote-containers

### Introduction

I'm currently trying to use **Remote container** of **VS Code** with **Fedora 36 Silverblue OS**.
And I configured the extension to use **Podman** instead of **Docker**.
The project with which I try to use the extension: https://github.com/beurtschipper/Depix

### Problem

When I try this, I obtain an empty project folder :
[image: Empty folder of Dev Container]

### Question

Does someone have the solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to add the following to your devcontainer.json:

```json
"remoteUser": "vscode",
"containerUser": "vscode"
"workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename},type=bind,Z",
"runArgs": [
  "--userns=keep-id"
]
```

After that, you can run *"Rebuild Container"* and it should work.

Sources:
[workspaceMount](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1333#issuecomment-874943603)
[runArgs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5539#issuecomment-912437433)